# Photoshop Script Add Filename to Image as Text, But Remove '-' character

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I found a script that will take the filename of my image and put it on the image, minus the file extension. I have added this to an action, which works exactly how I want it, however my filenames have '-' characters in them.

Is it possible to remove the '-' characters in the script? I haven't been able to get the replace function to work. (which I need).

This is the code that is working right now:

```
    // Now create a text layer at the front
    var myLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
    myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
    myLayerRef.name = "Filename";

    var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;

    // strip the extension off
    var fileNameNoExtension = docRef.name;
    fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split( "." );
    if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
        fileNameNoExtension.length--;
    }
    fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");    
    myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension.substring(2);


    // myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension.replace(/^-/i, '');


    // off set the text to be in the middle
    myTextRef.position = new Array( docRef.width / 2, docRef.height / 2 );
    myTextRef.size = 28;
}
```

Comment: `myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension.replace(/\-/g, '');`

Comment: Thankyou! :D this worked :)

Comment: How can I store my variable so I can run these both after each other?              myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension.substring(2); 
myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension.replace(/\-/g, ' ‘);